# How to dynamically control text_field property in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to set a rails form text_field property to read only when the model already contains a value.

Here is my code

```
<%= f.text_field :domain, class="span4", readonly: "true" %>
```

I want to avoid doing something verbose like:

```
<%if @model.domain.empty? %>
   <%= f.text_field :domain, class="span4"%>
<%else%>
   <%= f.text_field :domain, class="span4", readonly: "true" %>
<%end%>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :domain, class="span4", :disabled => !@model.domain.blank? %>
```

Comment: doesn't quite seem to work.  `readonly: !:domain.empty?` results in `readonly="readonly"` in the HTML output.

Comment: ok so the `readonly="readonly"` is the correct HTML output sorry, but when there is a value for :domain I get an `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: OK - the error I was getting was being caused by something else in the code, however I still cannot get `:domain.empty?` to return anything other than false.

Comment: try setting :disabled => !:domain.empty? instead of :readonly

Comment: I think the problem is that :domain.empty? is never true - even if the field value is empty.  @model.domain.empty? returns true, but :domain.empty? does not.

Comment: my bad, @model.domain is correct. However if domain is nil empty? will return an error. You should use blank? instead.